# Where can I buy spares for a Sussex shaft drive?

Tags: shaft

The crank arms and the crank shaft for my Dynamic Tempo 8 appear to be completely worn. Both crank arms just flop about when pedalling. Rumour has it that Dynamic have gone bust, but does anyone know where spare parts might still be available?
The crank arms themselves appear to be Truative powersplines.

Comment: are the crank splines damaged? Would new cranks fix your problem? Please clarify!

Comment: Could you add some photos?  Might be a write-off if the parts are weird.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [Dynamic Bicycles](https://dynamicbicycles.com/) has been focusing on fleet bikes rather than bikes sold to individuals. They must sell parts to their fleet customers. If you contact them maybe they will sell parts to you. [Here is the manual](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/8977889/owners-manual-for-all-chainless-bicycle-models-dynamic-bicycles/21) for their bikes.

Here is the website for [Sussex Shaft Drive](http://www.chainlessbike.cn/index_en.html), they might be worth a try. They might be able to point you to one of their dealers or retailers.

Another option would be to find a used one in good shape to use for parts.

[TruVativ is a brand](https://www.sram.com/en/truvativ) owned by SRAM
The [PowerSpline](https://www.sram.com/en/truvativ/models/bb-ps-a1) is a bottombrackt
TruVative also sells a [variety of cranksets](https://www.sram.com/en/truvativ/products/cranksets?filters=&sort=Relevancy&page=1)

It's hard to imagine that a standard crankset will work on your bike. My guess is that SRAM had them specially made for Sussex or Dynamic.